# creating scoped_lock for 200 ms max

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess, boost-mutex, scoped-lock

I am trying to create a timed scoped lock on mutex. I thought following api from boost could help but I am having hard time finding some sample code as reference to use it.

```
scoped_lock(mutex_type & m, const boost::posix_time::ptime & abs_time);
```

I want to do it something like this,

```
scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock (_mutex,  ? /* lock for 200 ms max */ ) ;
```

My question is how to create a posix_time::ptime object of duration 200ms. I tried to create time_duration object but their is no constructor that accepts it straight forward way.

```
boost::posix_time::time_duration td = boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200);
```

Can someone help me understand how it works please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the duration to the current time:

```
auto now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
```